# How do I change wordpress texts

Tags: wordpress

I'm pretty newbie with wordpress.

I already created my website based on template. I did couple changes on ".po" file, like:

```
#: wp-login.php:875 wp-login.php:950 wp-login.php:1010 wp-login.php:1112
#: wp-includes/general-template.php:324
msgid "Log in"
msgstr "Log into your awesome account"

...

#: wp-login.php:1347 wp-login.php:1391 wp-includes/general-template.php:466
msgid "Log In"
msgstr "Another Log In text"
```

None of them were changed. Why it happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.po` files are for translations to other languages, not to change what is displayed by your templates.

To change texts that are part of template files, you have to change the according php files in the theme folder. But that's not a good idea, since next time the theme is updated, these changed files will be replaced by the new files and your changes will be lost.

So to avoid that, it's best to use a **child theme**  and only include the files (as copies from the parent theme) where you want to make changes.

More on child themes here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: Hi Johannes, thanks for clarify. As I could read, it says about to make changes in "function.php". Do you think that add strings concatenating with html tags is a good practice?

Comment: You can use *any*  of the files of the original theme, copy that to the theme folder and modify that copy according to your needs - those files will "overrule" the ones with the same name in the parent theme folder. The "functions.php" and "style.css" are needed, but these can be minimal - everything that's not in there is inherited from the files of the parent theme.